# How to retrieve multiple images in hibernate from MySQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

**Hello,

How to retrieve images and show in JSP page from List.
i have tried many ways but not getting desired output.
I am using Hibernate with JPA, Servlets and MySQL DB.

please help.**

this is my DAO class

```
public class IndexDAO {
    public List<ItemModel> ls=null;

    public List getAll()
    {
        Session ses=HibernateUtil.getSf().openSession();
        try(ses) {

            String hql=" from com.imagineage.admin.ItemModel ";
            Query q = ses.createQuery(hql);
            ls=q.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ls;
    }
```

And This is Model Class.

```
package com imagineage admin 
import java io Serializable 
import javax persistence Column
import javax persistence Entity
import javax persistence GeneratedValue
import javax persistence Id
import javax persistence Lob
import javax persistence Table
import org hibernate annotations GenericGenerator
import lombok.Getter
import lombok.Setter
import lombok.ToString

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Getter
@ToString
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="ProductItems")
public class ItemModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MyItemGen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "MyItemGen",strategy = "com.imagineage.generators.ItemIDGen")
    @Column(name = "Item_ID")
    private String ItemID;
    private String ItemName;
    private Integer ItemQty;
    private Double ItemPrice;
    private String ItemDesc;

    @Lob
    private byte[] ItemImg;
    private String CatFk;



}
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Please explain what you are seeing now, and what you really want to see. Also, how are you storing "multiple images". If you truly have multiple images, you need a OneToMany relationship, instead of jam packing all images in one byte array. That will compromise the integrity of your binary data.

Comment: I am creating a index page of ecommerce website, which contains div tag with the product details, price and image. Dynamically i am adding those things as a admin from admin login and each div is comming on index page with all details but image is not comming. I have used a model class for all the details which is mentioned above, no there is no need of onetomany relation

Comment: I am storing one image at a time with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on my own.

```
<%


        for (ItemModel im : imodel) {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(im.getItemImg());
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);                  
            }

            byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
            String base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
            im.setBase64Image(base64Image);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
    %>
    <!-- <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right"> -->
    <!-- <div class="features_items">features_items -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${ItemModel.base64Image}" alt="" />
```